# Test UpdateView for useraccounts application

Tags: django, django-views

Test doesn't give status_code 302  in user profile UpdateView and so there's no updates occurs on the object
the model code

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    '''
    This a replaced user profile instead of the default django one
    '''
    language_choices=[('en',_('English')),('se',_('Swedish'))]

    email=models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Email'), max_length=128, blank=False, unique=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(verbose_name=_('First Name'), max_length=128)
    last_name=models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Last Name'), max_length=128)
    joined_at=models.DateField(
                                verbose_name=_('Joined at'),
                                auto_now_add=True,
                                blank=False
                                )
    language=models.CharField(
                            verbose_name=_('Language'),
                            max_length=2,
                            choices=language_choices,
                            default=language_choices[0][0]
                            )
    active=models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Active'), default=False)
    is_superuser=models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Is Superuser'), default=False)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Is Active'), default=True)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Is Staff'), default=False)
```

The form code

```
class EditUserForm(UserChangeForm):
    '''
    Profile form to update existing user information
    '''
    # error message for email matches
    error_messages = {
        'email_mismatch': _("The two email fields didn't match."),
        }
    # create field for email
    email1 = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("Email"),
        widget=forms.EmailInput,
        help_text=_("If you change your email your account will be inactive untill your reactivate by email link."),
    )
    # get the email from confirmed email field
    email2 = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("Confirm Email"),
        widget=forms.EmailInput,
        help_text=_("Enter the same email as before, for verification."),
    )
    # hide password field
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label="Password")

    class Meta:
        '''
        Initial fields and model for the form
        '''
        model = models.User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email1','email2', 'language')

    def clean_email2(self):
        '''
        Method for if email and confirmed email are the same
        This method works when confirmed email cleared
        '''
        # get the email from email field
        email1 = self.cleaned_data.get("email1")
        # get the email from confirmed email field
        email2 = self.cleaned_data.get("email2")
        # check if both emails are equal
        if email1 and email2 and BaseUserManager.normalize_email(email1) != BaseUserManager.normalize_email(email2):
            # give an error message if emails not matches
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['email_mismatch'],
                code='email_mismatch')
        # return the confirmed email
        return BaseUserManager.normalize_email(email2)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        '''
        Method tosave the edited user data
        '''
        # get the initial method
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        # set the email on the model field
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email1"]
        # save edited user data
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Method for initial values and functions for the SignUp form class
        '''
        # get user data from User model
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=kwargs['instance'])
        # get the initial form class values
        super(EditUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Add the current email as the inital email
        self.fields['email1'].initial = user.email
        # Add the current email as the intial confirmed email
        self.fields['email2'].initial = user.email
        # Add help text in the password field for change
        self.fields['password'].help_text=(
                    _("Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
                    "this user's password, but you can change the password "
                    "using <a href=\"{0}\">this form</a>.")
                    .format(reverse(
                        'core:ChangePassword',
                        kwargs={'pk':user.pk})))
```

and the view code

```
class EditUser(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    '''
    Class view to update user details
    '''
    # used template
    template_name = 'core/edit.html'
    # View model
    model = models.User
    # View form
    form_class = forms.EditUserForm

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == get_user_model().objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def get_success_url(self):
        '''
        Metho to redirect after a valid form
        '''
        # check if the email is verified
        if self.request.user.active:
            # get the user key
            pk=self.request.user.pk
            # redirect to profile details
            return reverse_lazy('core:details', kwargs={'pk':pk})
        else:
            # send a verification email
            return SendActivationEmail(self.request, self.request.user)
```

the test code

```
   self.viewuser_url = reverse('core:details', kwargs={'pk':self.user.pk})
   self.edituser_url = reverse('core:edit', kwargs={'pk':self.user.pk})

def test_edit_user_post(self):
        first_name = 'Osama'
        response = self.client.post(self.edituser_url,
            data={
                'first_name': first_name,
                'last_name': self.last_name,
                'email': self.email,
                })

        self.assertRedirects(response, self.viewuser_url)

        self.user.refresh_from_db()

        self.assertEqual(self.user.first_name, first_name)
```

I tried to get assertEqual for the status code and it gitves me 200 instead of 302

also I tried to enter the form details instead of model details and it gives me an error

The get test works fine and also permission test works great.. all the models, forms and urls test works perfect.

I don't know how I can test this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form isn't valid, then the form will be re-rendered with errors and you'll get a 200 response.

To debug the problem, check `response.context['form'].errors` in your test to see what the problem is.

```
    response = self.client.post(self.edituser_url,
        data={
            'first_name': first_name,
            'last_name': self.last_name,
            'email': self.email,
            })
    print(response.context['form'].errors
```

Your view uses `EditUserForm`, but you are not posting any values for `email1` or `email2`, so there is probably something in the errors about missing data.